# Other loop with unexpected output

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, factorial

I've this code and I don't understand the output. I was expecting an output 121.
I looking to understand this specific function  and not the factorial function.

Code:

```
function a($num) {
    static $totFac = 1;

    if($num > 0){
        $totFac = $totFac * $num;
        a($num - 1);
    }

    $totFac++;
    return $totFac;
}

$result = a(5);
echo 'result: '.$result;
```

Output:

```
126
```

Comment: `totFac++` doesn't look right to me. The mathematical definition of factorial doesn't usually involve adding one at any point.

Comment: `factoriala($num - 1);` -> `return factoriala($num - 1);` You want to return the value of your recursive call.

Comment: @kevin I know that but I just to know why the output is 126.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function a($num) {
    static $totFac = 1;
    if($num > 0){
        $totFac = $totFac * $num;
        echo 'totfac: '.$totFac . "<br>";
        return a($num - 1); //you have to return here to stop execution
    } else {
        $totFac++;
        return $totFac;
    }
}
$result = a(5);
echo 'result: '.$result;
?>
```

Look at the comment for explaination

Comment: Thanks now I know that I 've to return the result of recursion. That means  that the recursion don't stop when it  function is called inside. It still go to the end and repeat the process but I notice that is added 5 to $totFac only after the 5 iterations and not in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, the factorial of 5 is 120 explained as:

  ```
  5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120
  ```
- Second, this is how a factorial should look like with recursive call:

  ```
  function factorial($number) {
      if ($number < 2) { 
          return 1; 
      } else { 
          return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
      } 
  }
  ```
- If you don't mean factorial, then this is how it happens if I alter your function

  ```
  function a($num) {
      static $totFac = 1;

      if($num > 0){
          $totFac = $totFac * $num;
          echo "calc totFac: " . $totFac . "\n";
          a($num - 1);
      }

      $totFac++;
      echo "increment totFac: " . $totFac . "\n";
     return $totFac;
  }

  $result = a(5);
  echo 'result: '.$result;
  ```

This is the output of the echo

```
calc totFac: 5
calc totFac: 20
calc totFac: 60
calc totFac: 120
calc totFac: 120
increment totFac: 120
increment totFac: 121
increment totFac: 122
increment totFac: 123
increment totFac: 124
increment totFac: 125
result: 126
```

Comment: I know but I just want to know is why ,when I add $tofactorial++;  , the output is 126 and not 121.

Comment: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers. And he calls `$totFac++;` so 121 is explainable

Comment: But the output isn't 121, it is 126. That's the question.

Comment: this is Factorial explained https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial and in your code, you are miss-using `$totFac`as you are not using the return value from `a($num -1)`

Comment: @Pedro It's because you increment your variable (`$totFac++;`), which you are not supposed to. The function given above will output 120 when called on `factorial(5);`, which is the correct answer.

Comment: @mina.nsami No, 121 is not correct. Faculty of 5 is 120, as explained above - *and* in the link you provided!

Comment: I'm not looking for a factorial function.  I've already know but this specify function. I just want to know  why adding $totFac++  give me the output 126.

Comment: @Pedro .. it is because your calls are being stacked and the extra +5 to the 121 is because function call stack is finishing

Comment: @Pedro As I said above, it's because you do `$totFac++;` in every iteration, and there are 5 iterations of the function (as you call it on the number 5).